# Как исправить заданное предложение?

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь

Недавно исправляла предложение в тексте, но пришлось немного изменить его структуру. А как бы вы его исправили и объяснили знаки?

Это начало текста:  ***В нашем саду много разных деревьев и среди них мой – абрикос.***

Вероятно, имелось в виду "моё".

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ** (полный текст задания)

Как проставить в тексте пунктуацию, найти грамматические ошибки?

1. Пунктуационные (отсутствие знаков препинания; проставлены лишние знаки; на месте нужного знака стоит другой).
2. Грамматические (неправильно образована форма слова, построено словосочетание или предложение).

Абрикос

В нашем саду много разных деревьев и среди них мой – абрикос. Какой он красивый, особенно весной, когда зацветает…

Comment: Может, сместить тире и поставить запятую? ***В нашем саду много разных деревьев, и среди них – мой абрикос.***

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец запятая, как я понял, проанализировав Нацкорпус, не нужна. По-видимому, "среди них" не влияет на постановку запятой, это словосочетание можно убрать без изменения всего прочего предложения: *Проходя мимо газетного киоска, Олег заметил среди газет на прилавке несколько книг и **среди них** знакомую серебристо-серую обложку*. Убираем "среди них" и получаем не менее связное предложение. А вот тут, к примеру, запятая так и так нужна: *Ничего удивительного, что знающие люди, и **среди них** историк и географ Василий Татищев, советовали исправить атлас при помощи Большого чертежа.*

Comment: @Nektoid Я не думал о влиянии ***среди них*** на пунктуацию. Больше ориентировался на интонацию, а союз ***и*** рассматривал как присоединительный. После ***деревьев*** вообще можно поставить точку.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец лично я бы вообще написал так: *В нашем саду много разных деревьев – и мой абрикос*. Но разбираем то, что дано.

Comment: @Nektoid  так автор вопроса вроде бы дает возможность и для исправления структуры

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец исправление структуры и сокращение — разные вещи :)

Comment: @Nektoid Да. Написал... и сразу же начал ждать именно такого комментария :)  и ловите плюс :)

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец какой я предсказуемый :) Спасибо)

Answer (score 2):

Возможно, автор имел в виду "моё", а возможно, и нет. Поэтому предложу такие варианты:

- **В нашем саду много разных деревьев и среди них моё — абрикос.**
- **В нашем саду много разных деревьев и среди них — мой абрикос.**

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135760/discussion-on-answer-by-nektoid----).

Answer (score 1):

1. ***В нашем саду много разных деревьев, и среди них — мой абрикос.***

Предложение сложносочиненное, состоит из двух простых.

Оба простых предложения эллиптические, построены по схеме "обстоятельство – подлежащее". Тире во втором предложении интонационное.

2. Менее удачный вариант: *В нашем саду много разных деревьев, и среди них моё (дерево) — абрикос.*

Здесь второе предложение тоже эллиптическое, но неполное. И еще присоединительное уточнение.